get latest record for each certnumber based on createtime or certnumber field
I am trying to copy latest record for each cert number value. we have multiple documents for each cert and trying to get latest record for each cert and copy it into new collection.
here is data looks like:
{ "_id": ..., "certnumber":"123456", "createtime": "2024-02-03T16:42:20.324Z", "company": "A" ,.....}
{ "_id": ..., "certnumber":"123456", "createtime": "2024-02-03T16:32:20.324Z", "company": "A" ,.....}
{ "_id": ..., "certnumber":"123456", "createtime": "2024-02-02T14:28:20.324Z", "company": "A" ,.....}
{ "_id": ..., "certnumber":"123456", "createtime": "2024-02-02T13:22:20.324Z", "company": "A" ,.....}
{ "_id": ..., "certnumber":"654321", "createtime": "2024-02-05T17:42:20.324Z", "company": "B" ,.....}
{ "_id": ..., "certnumber":"654321", "createtime": "2024-02-05T16:42:20.324Z", "company": "B" ,.....}
{ "_id": ..., "certnumber":"654321", "createtime": "2024-02-03T15:32:20.324Z", "company": "B" ,.....}
{ "_id": ..., "certnumber":"654321", "createtime": "2024-02-03T14:22:20.324Z", "company": "B" ,.....}

I tried to gather latest records using below command and it works but it only returns 2 field. How do I pull whole document instead of only 2 field?
db.collectionname.aggregate(
   [
     { $sort: { certnumber: 1, createtime: 1} },
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: {certnumber : "$certnumber" },
           updatedDate: { $last: "$createtime" }
         }
     },
   ],
)


There are 2 ways to achieve this.

using $setWindowFields to compute the rank within certnumber and select only rank: 1 documents to the new collection.

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": "$certnumber",
      "sortBy": {
        "createtime": -1
      },
      "output": {
        "rank": {
          "$rank": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "rank": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "rank"
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection2"
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

similar to your current approach, do a $sort then select $first/$last $$ROOT document.

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "certnumber": 1,
      "createtime": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$certnumber",
      "lastDoc": {
        "$last": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$lastDoc"
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection2"
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Thanks a lot. This is what exaxctly I was looking for. I tried 2nd query and it worked.
